# Multisite Nginx reverse proxy routing to Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm running an Ubuntu 10.04 nginx server, with a reverse proxy to apache (to run munin monitoring).

This is an excerpt of my default Apache site file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/cache/munin/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
```

And an excerpt of my *example.com* nginx configuration file:

```
location /stats {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8090/;
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffers           32 4k;
}
```

Whenever I go to *example.com/stats*, nginx point to apache over port 8090, and apache serves up the munin web directory. It works great.

**But what if I wanted to add another domain, say *example.org*?** I'd have another nginx configuration file, but how would I make apache's `DocumentRoot` something else? Since the requests are coming into apache from nginx through localhost port 8090, how can apache determine which site the request is coming from, and which `DocumentRoot`/configuration to serve it with?

I'm assuming I will have to use the headers set by nginx (`$host;` or `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` variables?) in apache somehow...

Comment: Nginx passes the headers through to the backend server - one of which is the Host header. Just add a ServerName directive to your Apache VirtualHost block, and create one block per domain and Apache will serve the correct VirtualHost (using the Host header it receives). You could test it by accessing the apache page directly with something like `curl --header "Host: example.com" localhost:8090`

Comment: You can also run the next Apache's VirtalHost in another port, like you did with munin in 8090.

Comment: Ahh, okay. So apache sees the same information about the host just as if it was alone, serving the files firsthand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run several domains on one nginx.conf file. Try this:

```
server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090;
    server_name example.org;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
    }
}

server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090;
    server_name example.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
    }
}
```

then add have two virtual configs in your apache

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
ServerName example.org
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/cache/munin/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8090>
ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/cache/munin/www2
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```